# Call new scene on progress done

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to call for a new scene just when the progressBar is done. I have tried to call for it without closing the old scene and it went through, but now I would like it to open new scene and close the current one.

```
task.setOnSucceeded(evt ->{
            Parent root = null;
            try {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("indexapp.fxml"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage window =(Stage) ((Node) evt.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
        });
```

And the output is this

```
Exception in Application start methodjava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: /C:/Users/Given/IdeaProjects/Garbage_Collect_Sytem_Client/out/production/Garbage_Collect_Sytem/resource/applicationStart.fxml:8

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
at resource.Main.start(Main.java:29)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: resource.StartApp
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:598)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: resource.StartApp.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3427)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:585)
... 23 more Exception running application resource.Main
```

Comment: See if  https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest helps.

Comment: This is the error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: resource.StartApp.<init>()`. That tells you that `StartApp` does not have a no-argument constructor despite one being expected to exist. If that doesn't help you, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Sedrick thank you so much it went through. I've just followed what was done in that example.

Comment: Post an Answer to your own Question explaining the solution found. Later you will be able to mark that Answer as accepted by clicking the big green check mark.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did and it worked

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("applicationStart.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    StartApp mainController = loader.getController();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

    Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Given\\IdeaProjects\\App\\src\\resource");

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFile.length; i++) {
                updateProgress(i, listOfFile.length);
                updateMessage(listOfFile[i].getName());
                Thread.sleep(150);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    //The below code updates the message
    task.messageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String t1) {
            mainController.getField().setText(t1 + "Reading...");
        }
    });
    task.setOnSucceeded(ev ->{
        FXMLLoader innerLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("indexapp.fxml"));
        try
        {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Parent innerRoot = innerLoader.load();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(innerRoot));
            stage.show();
            primaryStage.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mainController.getBar().progressProperty().unbind();
    mainController.getBar().progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}
```